# How to get the column value based on multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to check rows where uid equal both `1` and `2` and if they do, return cid. In this example there will only ever be 2, but if you know a way to return the CID for more than 2, that would be great too.

How can I most easily get the value where cid = 5 when I know both `uid` values? (1,2).

```
 cid | uid |
------------
  5  |  1  |
  5  |  2  |
  6  |  1  |
  6  |  3  |
  7  |  1  |
  7  |  4  |
```

For pseudo sql, I am thinking something like `SELECT cid WHERE uid = 1 or uid = 2`

This returns all rows where uid has a 1 or a 2. How can I limit to an `OR` statement and an `AND`?

`SELECT cid WHERE uid = 1 AND uid = 2 (but in multiple rows)`

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to accomplish is not quite clear. I suggest you expand the example data provided and also include an example of the desired resulting data.

Comment: im just trying to figure out a select statement that can get me the value where cid = 5, if i know both UID values. 1 and 2.

Comment: In the example above, only ```cid```=5 has both 1 and 2, is it possible that any other ```cid``` could have the same combination of both 1 and 2?

Comment: no, it is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you're looking for a way to apply a condition to multiple rows, a way to do that is through agrupation functions. try this:

```
Select CID 
from YourTable where uid IN (1,2)
group by cid
having count(uid) = 2
```

in this example i'm using IN instead of two OR and i'm grouping the rows by CID, and after that i'm limiting the results to those rows that match with UID equals to 1 and 2.
There are many tricky ways of achieve the same result, for example you can also do something like:

```
Select CID 
from YourTable where uid IN (1,2)
group by cid
having sum(uid) = 3
```

in this example i'm suming the UID column, if UID is 1 and 2 the sum of both will result on 3, I assume that you can't have 3 rows with the UID 1 and the same CID

Answer (score 0):

According to given details, Try this. Let's say you have a table called `docs`;

```
SELECT d1.cid
FROM docs AS d1
LEFT JOIN docs AS d2 ON d1.cid = d2.cid
WHERE d1.uid = 1
AND d2.uid = 2
```